# Entity is not initialized

Tags: magento2, orders

I'm trying to build a function that gets orders of a customer by id but it gives me an exception: Entity is not initialized

that's my code

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\Orders\Model\Orders;

use VendorName\Orders\Api\Orders\MyOrdersInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class MyOrders extends AbstractCollection implements MyOrdersInterface
{

    /**
     * @api
     * @param int $customerId
     * @return array
     */
    public function getOrders($customerId){
        return [
            $this->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id',$customerId)->load()
        ];
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to define which class the Collection should use as a resource model and which class it should be a collection of.

You could take a look at [one of the existing collections](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/Customer/Model/ResourceModel/Customer/Collection.php), or [use the Mageplaza tutorial](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/how-to-create-crud-model-magento-2.html) (which is usually fine for the basic stuff).

You're looking for something like this:

```
    /**
     * Resource initialization
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(Model::class, ResourceModel::class);
    }
```

Remember to set `$_idFieldName`, `$_eventPrefix` and `$_eventObject` as well.

Comment: It's the most useful answer I've ever get. Big thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
protected $_orderCollectionFactory;
protected $orders;
public function __construct(
    .....
            \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
           .......
        ) {
    ...
    $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
    ........
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}


public function getOrders()
{

    if (!$this->orders) {
        $this->orders = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToSelect(
            '*'
        )->addFieldToFilter(
            'customer_id',
            $customerId
        )->setOrder(
            'created_at',
            'desc'
        );
    }
    return $this->orders;
}
```

Comment: what is $context and $order here?